# What is the equivalent of map() (from processing) in other languages?

Tags: java, processing

In [processing](http://processing.org) (a java based language) there's a very handy function called `map()` which takes 5 arguments. It re-maps a number from one range to another. Take a look at the official documentation [here](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) for detail.

I'm having trouble finding it's equivalent in other languages, especially in java. Or is the best solution to make my own function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just interpolating a value, which is equivalent to (following processing argument names):

```
map(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2) == 
   ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1)) * (stop2 - start2) + start2
```

This is rather trivial, indeed you turn your value into a value in `[0.0, 1.0]` which tells you how much near to start or stop it is (`0.0` at start1, `1.0` at stop1) and then you turn it into a value proportional to the other interval.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple calculation:

```
static double map(double value, double start1, double stop1, double start2, double stop2) {
    return (value - start1) / (stop1 - start1) * (stop2 - start2) + start2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Processing is open-source, so questions like these can be answered by looking at the source code on GitHub [here](https://github.com/processing/processing).

Specifically, [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L4869) is a link directly to the `map()` function, which looks like this:

```
static public final float map(float value,
                                float start1, float stop1,
                                float start2, float stop2) {
    float outgoing =
      start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1));
    String badness = null;
    if (outgoing != outgoing) {
      badness = "NaN (not a number)";

    } else if (outgoing == Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY ||
               outgoing == Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
      badness = "infinity";
    }
    if (badness != null) {
      final String msg =
        String.format("map(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) called, which returns %s",
                      nf(value), nf(start1), nf(stop1),
                      nf(start2), nf(stop2), badness);
      PGraphics.showWarning(msg);
    }
    return outgoing;
  }
```